# Unable to execute SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, import

I get the following error when trying to execute a stored procedure:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Hire_Termination, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 2]
> There is already an object named 'Employees' in the database

I created the table in another instance, I have to use a JSON file and import it into SQL Server:

```
USE [Kronos]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Hire_Termination]
AS
    DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(max)
    SET @JSON = N'{C:\Automation\Kronos.JSON}'
BEGIN
    SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Automation\Kronos.JSON', Single_Clob) import

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    INTO [Kronos].[dbo].[Employees]
    FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
END
```

Comment: What do you mean by created the table on another instance? The proc code will try to create new table `dbo.Employees` using `SELECT INTO` every time it's executed. Once the proc runs the first time, subsequent executions will error because the table already exists.

Comment: Don't randomly use 3 part names without a very good reason - it just becomes a maintenance problem. Your procedure is in the Kronos database - just use a 2 part name (schema.table) to reference the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT INTO` creates a new table. So instead of using

```
SELECT * 
INTO [Kronos].[dbo].[Employees]
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON);
```

use a regular `INSERT` statement e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [Kronos].[dbo].[Employees]
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON);
```

Note: Its best practice to fully list the columns you are inserted *and* selecting e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [Kronos].[dbo].[Employees] (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT INTO creates a new table. So the second time you run the SP, it will complain
If you want to insert into an existing table then use
INSERT INTO Kronos.dbo.Employees SELECT...
If you really want to just replace the contents of the table then you could run
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Kronos.dbo.Employees first, then SELECT INTO statement.